# Slow boot and functioning ubuntu 18.04

Tags: system-installation, live-usb

i bought an acer aspire A51515 about a month back.It has a core i5 8th gen processor, 8 gigs of ram, and ask me if you need something else. It came preinstalled with Ubuntu, but for some reason the retailer installed windows 10 after i bought it. So i installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with USB installation, completely erasing the disk first in the installation options menu. The problem now is that where people say Ubuntu takes 10 seconds to boot, my laptop takes about 5 minutes.I'm relatively new to Linux so i have'nt really tried much except reinstalling Ubuntu 3 times or so.

output of `dmesg`

```
[ 2342.150225] i2c_hid i2c-ELAN0501:01: i2c_hid_get_input: incomplete report (14/65535)
```

this is the output to `systemd-analyze critical-chain`

```
graphical.target @9min 54.149s
└─multi-user.target @9min 54.149s
└─snapd.seeded.service @3min 20.246s +6min 33.902s
└─basic.target @2min 34.839s
└─sockets.target @2min 34.839s
└─snapd.socket @2min 34.839s +461us
└─sysinit.target @2min 34.773s
└─cryptsetup.target @2min 34.773s
└─systemd-ask-password-wall.path @9.550s
└─-.mount @9.546s
└─system.slice @9.550s
└─-.slice @9.546s
```

and `inxi -F`

```
System: Host: PUTER Kernel: 4.18.0-15-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Gnome 3.28.3
Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Machine: Device: laptop System: Acer product: Aspire A515-51 v: V1.17 serial: N/A
Mobo: KBL model: Charmander_KL v: V1.17 serial: N/A UEFI [Legacy]: Insyde v: V1.17 date: 03/20/2018
Battery BAT1: charge: 37.5 Wh 82.2% condition: 45.6/48.9 Wh (93%)
CPU: Quad core Intel Core i5-8250U (-MT-MCP-) cache: 6144 KB
clock speeds: max: 1600 MHz 1: 820 MHz 2: 1115 MHz 3: 1094 MHz 4: 822 MHz 5: 1078 MHz 6: 1106 MHz
7: 1056 MHz 8: 1166 MHz
Graphics: Card: Intel UHD Graphics 620
Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.20.1 ) driver: i915 Resolution: 1366x768@59.97hz
OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel UHD Graphics 620 (Kabylake GT2) version: 4.5 Mesa 18.2.2
Audio: Card Intel Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel Sound: ALSA v: k4.18.0-15-generic
Network: Card-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller driver: r8169
IF: enp1s0f1 state: down mac: 98:29:a6:3f:37:f9
Card-2: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter driver: ath10k_pci
IF: wlp2s0 state: up mac: e8:2a:44:6b:de:33
Drives: HDD Total Size: 1000.2GB (0.7% used)
ID-1: /dev/sda model: WDC_WD10SPZX size: 1000.2GB
Partition: ID-1: / size: 916G used: 6.3G (1%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda1
RAID: No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors: System Temperatures: cpu: 29.8C mobo: 27.8C
Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info: Processes: 268 Uptime: 48 min Memory: 1337.3/7852.2MB Client: Shell (bash) inxi: 2.3.56
```

Comment: Please add the output of `systemd-analyze blame`, you may use https://paste.ubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been rectified. The laptop came with a faulty hard drive!!